# How to insert & get images usin linq

Tags: linq

First

```
id      (int)             
name (varchar)          
picture (image)
```

Second

```
id (int)      
post (varchar)    
age (int)
```

1. I want to add a record in first table.
2. Then I want to combine these two table using id.
3. Then I want to fill a gridview where the post is "manager".

(Especially I want to know how to insert image to database and how to display them using grid view.)

Comment: Are you using `linq-to-entities` ? What have you tried?

Comment: simply i want to store images in sql database and get them back to the grid view.

Comment: Is this an answer to gideon? There's a lot of information on the internet on storing images in databases. Answering your question requires writing an almost full-blown application.

Answer (score 0):

To insert an image to your table , you can try something like this on click of your save button

```
    string fileName = FileUpload1.FileName;
    byte[] fileByte = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
    Binary binaryObj = new Binary(fileByte);
    DataClasses1DataContext context = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    //mem_images is the name of the table you dragged , use your table name here
    context.mem_images.InsertOnSubmit(new mem_image { mem_img=binaryObj  });
    context.SubmitChanges();
    Response.Write("<script>alert('Image Has Been Saved Successfully'</script>);
```

To retrieve the image from the database table you will need to use a generic handler(.ashx) file , right click on your project and then go to add and then new item and finally Generic Handler.Here is the code for your .ashx file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;

namespace CwizBankApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for $codebehindclassname$
    /// </summary>

    public class ShowImage : IHttpHandler
    {


        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            //context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
           // context.Response.Write("Hello World");
            string id =context.Request.QueryString["Id"];


            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            Stream strm = ShowEmpImg(id);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
            while (byteSeq > 0)
            {
                context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, byteSeq);
                byteSeq = strm.Read(buffer, 0, 4096);
            }
        }
        public Stream ShowEmpImg(string id)
        {


            DataClasses1DataContext context1 = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            var r = (from a in context1.mem_images where a.image_id==id select a).First() ;
            return new MemoryStream(r.mem_img.ToArray());
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then finally in the click event of your show image or whatever do this

```
custImage1.ImageUrl = "~/ShowImage.ashx?Id="+textbox.text
```

Hope this helps you , if you have issues further , reply back